# Stretch div element over Y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fixed element that resides on bottom right corner. However its really small and i want to stretch it on `Y` axis to make it works as it should.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('<div />');
    $('<div />', {
        id: 'firster',
        style: 'position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; max-width: 500px;'
    }).appendTo('body');

    $('<iframe />'); // Create an iframe element
    $('<iframe />', {
        name: 'frame1',
        id: 'frame1',
        src: 'https://api.jquery.com/add/'
    }).appendTo('#firster');

});
```

Here is a preview of how it looks so far. The pink lines represents the area that that div should cover.

[image]

Tried to set `width: 600px; height: 100%` on that div with `firster` id, but it did not work.

The results that i get when i do set `width: 600px; height: 100%` are basically moving that same size element left and right.

Comment: Have you tried setting `width: 100%; height: 100%;` on the iframe?

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo I didnt. Was only focused on the div part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `height: 100%` on `#firster`, the browser actually does not know what `100%` means: it has to be relative to a certain parent value. In this case, you are better off using `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` on the element. This will force it to stretch to the full height of the viewport. Alternatively you can also use `top: 0` and `height: 100vh` (`100vh` meaning 100% of the viewport height), but this is less widely supported.

Then declare `height: 100%` on the nested `<iframe>` element. It will now have a proper reference/ruler to compute the `100%` against, which is in this case, the full height of the viewport.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('<div />', {
        id: 'firster',
        style: 'position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; max-width: 500px;'
    }).appendTo('body');

    $('<iframe />', {
        name: 'frame1',
        id: 'frame1',
        src: 'https://api.jquery.com/add/'
    })
    .css('height', '100%')
    .appendTo('#firster');

});
```